# Tracking installed dependencies of a Python package for uninstallation

Tags: python, pip, package, dependency-management

The current behaviour of `pip`:

Imagine a Python package `spam`. It has three dependencies - packages `package1`, `package2`, and `package3`. When user installs the package `spam` with the `pip`, none of the dependencies have been installed by the user earlier and thus all three dependencies are installed as well. When user uninstalls the package with the `pip`, only the `spam` package is deleted - its dependencies are left untouched.

I wonder whether another scenario could be implemented:

At the moment when user installs the package `spam` with the `pip`, `package1` package has already been installed by the user earlier and thus only two dependencies are installed. When user uninstalls the package with the `pip`, he can choose whether to delete the dependencies that have been installed during the installation of the `spam` package. That is, `package1` was already present, we do not want to delete it, however, `package2` and `package3` have been installed during the installation of `spam` and user may explicitly say: "I want to delete the dependencies of this package that have been installed during the package installation".

The motivation behind this is that there is a Python package that has very many dependencies and I wonder whether there is any smart way to allow user to clean up its dependencies upon uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autoremove` instead of `uninstall`:

```
pip install pip-autoremove
pip-autoremove spam -y
```

Where `spam` is your package.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. `pip-autoremove` removes "unused dependencies", but `package1` might not be the dependency of some other package but just something that is used in scripts written by OP.

Comment: @FlyingTeller, this is exactly the situation. `package1` can be used by any Python programs I have, so I do not want to uninstall `package1` when I uninstall `spam`.

Comment: How would `pip-autoremove` detect that I have some script lying around that does `import package1` though?